# How pass parameter in this method?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, backend, django-orm

Hello I'm newbie Python user.

I study now django queryset. but

[query.pyi in _BaseQuerySet's method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlSlX.png)

```
def values(self, *fields: Union[str, Combinable], **expressions: Any) -> ValuesQuerySet[_T, Dict[str, Any]]: ...
```

I want to pass a parameter to that function, but the first code runs, but the second code does not.

here is error code

```
valuelist = ("col1", "col2")

comment = Comment.objects.annotate(col1=F("contents"), col2=F("comment_depth")).values(valuelist)
```

and showed up if above code run

```
          Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "D:\Ryan\conda\envs\djangostudy\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
       response = get_response(request)
     File "D:\Ryan\conda\envs\djangostudy\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
       response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
     File "D:\Ryan\conda\envs\djangostudy\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
       return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
     File "D:\Ryan\conda\envs\djangostudy\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py", line 114, in view
       return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
     File "D:\Ryan\conda\envs\djangostudy\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 505, in dispatch
       response = self.handle_exception(exc)
     File "D:\Ryan\conda\envs\djangostudy\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
       self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
     File "D:\Ryan\conda\envs\djangostudy\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
       raise exc
     File "D:\Ryan\conda\envs\djangostudy\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 502, in dispatch
       response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
     File "D:\djangostudy\DjangoStudy\member\views.py", line 79, in memberlistrlist                                                                   nt_depth")).values(valuelist)
       comment = Comment.objects.annotate(col1=F("contents"), col2=F("commes\query.py", line 841, in valuesment_depth")).values(valuelist)
     File "D:\Ryan\conda\envs\djangostudy\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 836, in _valuesels\query.py", line 841, in values
       clone = self._values(*fields, **expressions)
     File "D:\Ryan\conda\envs\djangostudy\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 836, in _values
       clone.query.set_values(fields)
     File "D:\Ryan\conda\envs\djangostudy\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 2172, in set_values
       self.add_fields(field_names, True)
     File "D:\Ryan\conda\envs\djangostudy\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1863, in add_fields
       join_info = self.setup_joins(name.split(LOOKUP_SEP), opts, alias, allow_many=allow_m2m)
    ttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'
    14/Mar/2021 19:14:09] "GET /member/memberlist/ HTTP/1.1" 500 116044
```

not error code

```
comment = Comment.objects.annotate(col1=F("contents"), col2=F("comment_depth")).values("col1", "col2")
```

What should I do to get it running normally?

Comment: Please, don't post images of code, error, etc.

Comment: `.values(*value_list)` with an asterisk.

Comment: Please copy *code fragments*, not *images* of code fragments: idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: sorry guys... i edited it

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the `.values(…)` clause: you can not pass a tuple as parameter. You use *iterable unpack* to unpack the values of an iterable as individual parameters. This is done by putting an asterisk (`*`) in front:

```
Comment.objects.annotate(
    col1=F('contents'),
    col2=F('comment_depth')
).values(*valuelist)
```

That being said, often it is *not* a good idea to work with [**`.values(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values) since it "erodes" the model layer.

Comment: Why is this code interpreting badly in the Django model section? I just, I only wanted to keep it concise by defining several columns in the form of tuples.

Comment: Using `.values` means you are no longer working with `Comment` objects, but with dictionaries, this thus means that you no longer fetch objects through `ForeignKey`s, evaluate properties, etc.: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/over-use-of-values.html